# Is it possible to switch between two UI form in one class in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have following two classes with their UI forms.

1. loginWindow
2. mainWindow

Now when I need to go to the mainWindow I click on the push button in loginWindow and a **new window pops up** that is the mainWindow.

```
void LoginWindow::on_pbLogin_clicked()
{
    MainWindow *mainW = new MainWindow;
    mainW->show();
}
```

What I am trying to have is to get the contents of mainWindow in the loginWindow.
I could switch/move to mainWindow from LoginWindow in the same window, without mainWindow creating its own window to show its content and I don't want to use **qstackedwidget**

Is it possible? if yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the two different interfaces to show in the *same window*, or do you want to popup a *new window* and hide the original window?  Why don't you want to use a `QStackedWIdget`?

Comment: Hide and show controls based on requirement. HIde "main window" controls when you need login details. Show main window controls when you  need mainwindow. you can dynamically resize them. As you are hiding, the controls can be overlapped also.

Comment: QMainWindow is kinda special. Maybe just have two windows, just make then 2nd window have same geometry as 1st, so user might not even notice the change. Alternatively, implement the login view as the central widget of thr QMainWindow, and hide docks, menus and whatever in the login state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that `LoginWindow` and `MainWindow` are both derived from `QMainWindow` (otherwise it wouldn't just be a content switch), then one option other than using a `QStackedWidget` would be to have the two form classes derive from `QWidget` and use either as the `centralWidget` of a single `QMainWindow` instance.

Comment: It is working. But how can I get back (by clicking on a push button) from the mainWindow to the loginWindow?

loginWindow is derived from QMainWindow and
mainWindow is derived from QWidget.

Is it possible?

Comment: As I said: derive both content classes from `QWidget` and use both, one at a time, as the central widget of the same `QMainWindow`.
Switching back and forth is then just a matter of calling `setCentralWidget` with the correct content. You can either keep both content widgets around or always delete the one currently not in use and recreate on switch.